# Scosta smart card memory unvailable after a sequence of create and delete files

Tags: smartcard, scosta

Activity(Process):

1. Select MF.
2. Create DF(with 800 bytes).
3. Select DF.
4. Create EF(with 800 bytes).
5. Select MF.
6. Delete DF.

The activity shown above was repeated several times such that after some time i got error in creating EF (memory not available in file)(step 4).
After some time i got the same error in creating DF(step 2).
I feel like im loosing memory and not able to gain back after deletion.
Please any suggestion woulf be helpful.

Comment: What APDU, do you use for delete EF?

Comment: My best assumption is, that deleting the DF leaves the EF as existing, but no longer accessible. Try deleting the EF explicitly first before deleting the DF.

Comment: @vikky APDU = 00 e4 00 00 02 (2 bytes DF file ID) ...... also i have tried selecting the DF and using 00 e4 00 00.....

Comment: @guidot Yeah looks like possible reason.. thanks will check that. But another issue is that i dont know the complete memory size of my card. Now after trying with new methods i still cannot verify that suggested delete procedure is the right one. The specs say you can pass the id to delete or not pass to delete the selected one.

Comment: As per my knowledge, Scosta card comes with 32K and 64k memory.

Comment: What is the ATR of the card

Comment: ATR = 0x3b    0x3f    0x11    0x0     0x80    0x12    0x0     0x91    0x31    0xc0    0x64    0xe     0x1     0x46    0xac       0x72    0xf7    0x41    0x5

Comment: Yeah i was expecting 64K memory. Is there any way to get back the lost memory.